# Rails 4 app not connecting to Stripe

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

Trying to add stripe payments to my app,  but its not connecting.
installed the stripe gem , restarted the server & added my stripe API keys (test) 
Added the javascript info so it connects the my stripe account

So when i buy something enter CC details it should connect to stripe.

Have also turned off turbolinks but still does the same. What i need is a pop up from stripe to i know its working.

orders.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  payment.setupForm()

payment =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_order').submit ->
        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
        Stripe.card.createToken($('#new_order'), payment.handleStripeResponse)
        false
  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      alert(response.id)
    else
      alert(response.error.message)
```

show.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <%= image_tag @listing.image.url %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h3><%= @listing.name %></h3>
    <p><%= number_to_currency(@listing.price) %></p>
    <p><%= @listing.description %></p>
    <br>
    <div class="center">
      <%= link_to "Buy it Now", new_listing_order_path(@listing), class: "btn btn-primary", data: { no_turbolink: true } %>
  </div>
</div>

<% if current_user == @listing.user %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_listing_path(@listing), class: "btn btn-link" %> |
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', listings_path, class: "btn btn-link" %>
```

orders._form.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <%= image_tag @listing.image.url %>
      </div>
      <h3><%= @listing.name %></h3>
      <h4><%= number_to_currency(@listing.price) %></h4>
    </div>

      <div class="col-md-8">

        <%= form_for([@listing, @order]) do |f| %>
          <% if @order.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h4><%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this order from being saved:</h4>

              <ul>
              <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
              <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
          <% end %>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :address %>
            <%= f.text_field :address, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :city %>
            <%= f.text_field :city, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :state %>
            <%= f.text_field :state, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>



          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
                <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "number", class: "form-control" } %>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <%= label_tag :card_code, "CVC" %>
                <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "cvc", class: "form-control" } %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag nil, "Expiration Date" %>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <%= select_month nil, { use_two_digit_numbers: true }, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "exp-month", class: "form-control" } %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <%= select_year nil, { start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+10 }, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "exp-year", class: "form-control" } %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Complete Order", class: "btn btn-success" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if any JS errors are occurring?

Comment: yes i checked no JS errors

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to trigger the Stripe function from a form that doesn't exist. You have several references to:

```
$('#new_order')
```

It looks like your form id is actually new listing order:

```
$('#new_listing_order')
```

But check the generated HTML, or inspect element, to be sure.

Comment: tried it but does not connect to stripe. the new listing order is the form used to enter address details and credit card details. when you complete the order it should connect to stripe payments

Comment: I suspect its at least required to work. Could you update your code in the question with what you have now, including the two references to the new_listing_order id?